# Is there any possible way that I can manipulate foreign keys in my cakephp model associations?

Tags: sql, cakephp, model

I am doing a one-to-many relationship in my codes right now. Below is my db:

```
TABLE: categories
FIELDS: category_id (primary)
        categoryName


TABLE: products
FIELDS: id (primary)
        productName
        category_id
```

I want products.category_id communicate with categories.category_id so that it will select products with its corresponding  category_id. But what actually happens in my code is it select category_id via the id in my products which is my primary key and it goes like this:

```
SELECT `Category`.`category_id`, `Category`.`categoryName`, `Category`.`description`, `Category`.`picture` FROM `categories` AS `Category` WHERE `Category`.`category_id` IN (3, 5, 6)
```

the values: 3,5,6 are the primary keys of the three products in my products table. But it should be this way

```
SELECT `Category`.`category_id`, `Category`.`categoryName`, `Category`.`description`, `Category`.`picture` FROM `categories` AS `Category` WHERE `Category`.`category_id` IN (1, 2, 3)
```

where the values: 1,2,3 are the category_id in my products table corresponding with the category_id in my categories table

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Post your associations and the code you're using for the find.  (and change 'category_id' to 'id')

Comment: got is solved Dave. My mistake that as a newbie, I did not follow the naming convention of cakephp and after doing so, I exchanged the model associations of my two models.

for Product model:

    var $belongsTo = 'Category';


for Category model:

    var $hasMany = 'Product';


and everything else worked. Thank yah  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your model associations are set up correctly:

```
//Category model
public $hasMany = array('Product');

//Product model
public $belongsTo = array('Category');
```

And change `Category.category_i`d to just `Category.id`.